# Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: c#, mysql, system

In my database Cashier and ID are Primary Key

```
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView2.Items)
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO tblrecord values 
    (@ID,@Description,@Price,@Quantity,@TotalSum,@Type,@Size,@Brand,@DateTime)"; 

    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDesc.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtPrice.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSum", txtSum.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", txtType.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", txtSize.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", txtBrand.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", lblDate.Text);

    cm.ExecuteNonQuery(); //ExecuteNonQuery passes a connection string to database or SQL.

    string sql2 = @"INSERT INTO tblcashierrecord values 
    (@Cashier,@PID,@Descrip,@Price,@Quantity,@TotalSum,@Type,@Size,@Brand,@DateTime)";                  
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cashier", lblUser.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", txtID.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrip", txtDesc.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtPrice.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txtQuantity.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalSum", txtSum.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", txtType.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", txtSize.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", txtBrand.Text);

    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", lblTimer.Text);
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If don't explain better what is your problem adding more context to your code (what line throws the exception?, what are the PrimaryKeys of your tables? What input values are passed for those PrimaryKey?) then do not be surprised if your question is downvoted and closed. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

"foreach" is a loop.
And in every iteration the ID is filled with the contents of txtID.text
So, the second iteration will give you the duplicate key error.

Comment: so it should no looping or no foreach there ?

Comment: I cannot see any relation between listView2.Items and your textboxes.
If the relation exists you need to extract the fields from listView2.Items.